# Ruby Telegram bot - How to get a text from user message and put it into a variable?

Tags: ruby, bots, telegram

I need to get an integer from user's message and put it to a variable day.
How can I do that?

here's bit of code:

```
Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|
bot.listen do |message|
case message.text
when '/start'
  bot.api.sendMessage(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Привет, #{message.from.first_name}. Чтобы узнать сегодняшнее расписание, напишите /today")

when '/today'

  bot.api.sendMessage(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "#{date}")
if discipline1_name.size == 0 && discipline2_name.size == 0 && discipline3_name.size == 0 && discipline4_name.size == 0 && discipline5_name.size == 0 && discipline6_name.size == 0 then
    (bot.api.sendMessage(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Сегодня воскресенье, можете отдыхать :)")
    bot.api.sendMessage(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Чтобы узнать расписание на другой день, введите дату в формате /13 (13 - день)."))
else
  unless discipline1_name.size == 0
    bot.api.sendMessage(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "1. #{discipline1_name} в кабинете #{discipline1_cab}")
  else
    bot.api.sendMessage(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "1. ===========")
  end
```

and like that it goes down for discipline2, 3, ... 6

what I need is something like this:

```
when '#{message}'
day = message.to_i
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://rating.ivpek.ru/timetable/timetable/show?gid=222&date=2017-10-#{day}"))
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you complement your question? Which library are you using?, are you using webhooks or polling?

Comment: I'm using telegram-bot-ruby-0.8.4 lib, I don't use webhooks and polling

Comment: What do you have so far? How do you retrieve the message? How does the message look like? Did you read the documentation? Could you show some code?

Comment: now I have a bot that can scrap some information from site and that's all. you can see code here https://github.com/nil-kh/telegram-bot-timetable-202

Comment: message has to look like '/13' where 13 is a day

Comment: @rafulin don't just refer to a 3rd party site, make sure to include the relevant parts of your question here (that includes code). And don't post comments for clarification, [edit] your question instead.

Comment: i edited question look at it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
num = message.text.to_i
```

You don't need the whole `case` statement if the only valid thing for users to send to you is a number.

If you do use a case statement, you should use a default case using the `else` keyword instead of the weird thing you're trying to do where the message is matched against itself.